Insert JSON object into JSON array column
I am working on a small project to learn Supabase and NextJS. I am trying to add a JSON object to my sites array which is defined as a JSON array. I want to add the config (and more in the future) to the sites column based on the user's id that I get back from auth().

This is what I could come up with but I keep getting this error:
message: expected JSON array. I've tried wrapping the object with brackets to create an array and that doesn't work either.
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from("users")
  .insert({
    sites: {...}) // config object
  .eq("id", user?.id);

I've tried different Filters per Supabase docs and nothing is working. There doesn't seem to be a clear way to update arrays with JSON from what I've searched, but I'm also very new to PostgreSQL databases.

"which is defined as a JSON array" - don't use json[]. Make it json, then store an array value.

so are you saying for my insert go from this: .insert({sites: {...}) to this =>  .insert([sites: {...}]) ?

Also, when trying the to do that I get message: null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint

No. .insert({sites: {...}}) (or rather .insert({sites: [{...}]})) is fine, but you should change the column type in the database.

I was able to solve with the following:
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from("users")
  .update({
    sites: [
      ...stateUser.sites, // previous JSON objects
      testConfig(timestampWithTimeZone, stateUser?.sites), // new JSON object
    ],
  })
  .eq("id", stateUser?.id)
  .select();

Hope this will help someone else in the future!
